# IdentityServer on AKS

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, nginx, kubernetes, azure-devops

I'm trying to setup our platform on a Kubernetes cluster (AKS, Azure) with Azure DevOps.

I'm currently stuck on having the websites up & running, but I can't login.\

My Ingress controller logs:

```
2019/12/15 15:37:27 [error] 790#790: *1135318 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream
```

My application logs:

```
CORS request made for path: /Account/Login from origin: null but was ignored because path was not for an allowed IdentityServer CORS endpoint
```

And it's an IdentityServer4 project on .NET Core 3.1.

We use Docker containers, an AKS Cluster, using Azure DevOps (connection made by using the tools inside Azure, so it's all generated for us)

We

Please let me know if you need any other information!

We are exposing it to HTTPS through our load balancer, it's setup using cert-manager that uses Let's Encrypt (this works).

Also, if I try to connect using OIDC to the server from one of my web portals, it tries to do so over an http connection. This shouldn't happen because we did the steps for setting it all up with HTTPS.

So the two questions are:
Is there anything we missed regarding http vs https when connecting to the identityserver4 project?
How can we fix this issue regarding headers being too big?

The yaml we use in our 'Generate kubernetes manifest file' step on Azure DevOps:

```
'# $(appName)/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: $(appName)
  labels:
    app: $(appName)
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: $(appName)
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: $(appName)
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: $(appName)
          image: somelinktoimage.com/somename:$(Build.BuildId)
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP

---

# $(appName)/service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: $(appName)
  labels:
    app: $(appName)
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: http
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    app: $(appName)

---

# $(appName)/service-ingress.yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: some-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.org/proxy-connect-timeout: "30s"
    nginx.org/proxy-read-timeout: "20s"
    nginx.org/client-max-body-size: "4m"
    nginx.org/proxy-buffer-size: "128k"
    nginx.org/proxy-buffers: "4256k"
    nginx.org/proxy-busy-buffers-size: "256k"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - account.dapperdino.co.uk
    secretName: some-secret-name
  rules:
  - host: account.dapperdino.co.uk
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: $(appName)
          servicePort: 80
        path: /(.*)' | Set-Content $(Agent.TempDirectory)/manifest.yaml
```

Comment: I came across this article: https://andrewlock.net/fixing-nginx-upstream-sent-too-big-header-error-when-running-an-ingress-controller-in-kubernetes/

But I don't know how to translate this to my workflow

Comment: The article seems pretty straight forward. You need to create [configmap](https://andrewlock.net/fixing-nginx-upstream-sent-too-big-header-error-when-running-an-ingress-controller-in-kubernetes/#creating-the-configmap) and then edit you nginx-ingress deployment and [add `--configmap` parameter](https://andrewlock.net/fixing-nginx-upstream-sent-too-big-header-error-when-running-an-ingress-controller-in-kubernetes/#configuring-the-nginx-ingress-controller-to-use-your-configmap). That's it. Remember to make sure the configmap is in the same namespace as your nginx-ingress deployment.

Comment: Thanks, we eventually managed to get it working in azure devops